# Таймер переключения Windows в спящий режим

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, wmi

Как в C# считать значения таймера, по которому ОС переключает комп в спящий режим? Может какой-то WMI класс это позволяет? Надо, чтобы до засыпания компа успеть сделать ряд действий из приложения. Когда сработал event - мне уже поздно... Надо за 1 минуту до срабатывания таймера выполнить ряд операций...

Либо второй вариант: не допустить включения спящего режима. М.б. в WMI есть доступ к параметру управления электропитанием. Я бы из своего приложения устанавливал в нем "Никогда", для того, чтоб пользователь при использовании моего приложения не мог назначать режим энергосбережения.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [SystemEvents](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents?view=netframework-4.8).

Подпишитесь на событие [PowerModeChanged](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.powermodechanged?view=netframework-4.8) и в его обработчике выполняйте нужные действия.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged;
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged(object sender, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Mode == PowerModes.Suspend)
        Console.WriteLine("sleep");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("awake");
}
```

Я только что опробовал этот код в консольном приложении. Работает.

---

> Надо за 1 минуту до срабатывания таймера выполнить ряд операций

С помощью функции [GetLastInputInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getlastinputinfo) [определяете](https://blog.aaronlenoir.com/2016/02/16/detect-system-idle-in-windows-applications-2/), когда система находится в состоянии простоя. И запускаете свой таймер с интервалом срабатывания на минуту меньше, чем время до перехода в спящий режим.

Единственная проблема: с ходу я не нашёл, как узнать это время до перехода в спящий режим.

Comment: `Because this is a static event, you must detach your event handlers when your application is disposed, or memory leaks will result.` Нужно в ответ добавить.

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл. Поверил. Работает (типа Veni, Vidi, Vici)
CallNtPowerInformation с параметром 12.