# Как получить варианты из выпадающего списка перехода компьютера в спящий режим в C#

Tags: c#, cmd, powershell

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда запускаю свою программу, в выпадающем списке должны быть варианты значений идентичны тем которые есть в выпадающем списке в настройках операционной системы. Как мне получить эти значения?

Я уже знаю как изменить эти значения (powercfg /change ...), а так же --как получить текущее значение?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1208720/184217

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Не думаю что это то что мне нужно. Мне надо время узнать время с Панель управления\Электропитание\Изменение параметров схемы

Comment: Эти значения можно получить с помощью WinAPI-функции `CallNtPowerInformation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эти значения можно получить с помощью WinAPI-функции [CallNtPowerInformation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/powerbase/nf-powerbase-callntpowerinformation).

Пример:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

```
static void Main()
{
    SYSTEM_POWER_POLICY spp;

    uint retval = NativeMethods.CallNtPowerInformation(
        NativeMethods.SystemPowerPolicyDc,
        IntPtr.Zero,
        0,
        out spp,
        Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SYSTEM_POWER_POLICY))
    );

    if (retval == NativeMethods.STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("От батареи:");
        Console.WriteLine("Отключать дисплей:  " + spp.VideoTimeout);
        Console.WriteLine("Усыплять компьютер: " + spp.IdleTimeout);
    }

    retval = NativeMethods.CallNtPowerInformation(
        NativeMethods.SystemPowerPolicyAc,
        IntPtr.Zero,
        0,
        out spp,
        Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SYSTEM_POWER_POLICY))
    );

    if (retval == NativeMethods.STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("От сети:");
        Console.WriteLine("Отключать дисплей:  " + spp.VideoTimeout);
        Console.WriteLine("Усыплять компьютер: " + spp.IdleTimeout);
    }
}
```

Время в секундах.

Выглядит несложно, однако для её использования нужно определить множество структур и перечислений. Их код взят с сайте [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/powrprof/SYSTEM_POWER_POLICY.html).

```
static class NativeMethods
{
    public const int SystemPowerPolicyAc = 0;
    public const int SystemPowerPolicyDc = 1;

    public const uint STATUS_SUCCESS = 0;

    [DllImport("powrprof.dll")]
    public static extern uint CallNtPowerInformation(
        int InformationLevel,
        IntPtr InputBuffer,
        int InputBufferLength,
        out SYSTEM_POWER_POLICY spi,
        int OutputBufferLength
    );
}

public enum POWER_ACTION : uint
{
    PowerActionNone = 0,      // No system power action.
    PowerActionReserved,      // Reserved; do not use.
    PowerActionSleep,         // Sleep.
    PowerActionHibernate,     // Hibernate.
    PowerActionShutdown,      // Shutdown.
    PowerActionShutdownReset, // Shutdown and reset.
    PowerActionShutdownOff,   // Shutdown and power off.
    PowerActionWarmEject,     // Warm eject.
}

[Flags]
public enum PowerActionFlags : uint
{
    POWER_ACTION_QUERY_ALLOWED = 0x00000001,  // Broadcasts a PBT_APMQUERYSUSPEND event to each application to request permission to suspend operation.
    POWER_ACTION_UI_ALLOWED = 0x00000002,     // Applications can prompt the user for directions on how to prepare for suspension. Sets bit 0 in the Flags parameter passed in the lParam parameter of WM_POWERBROADCAST.
    POWER_ACTION_OVERRIDE_APPS = 0x00000004,  // Ignores applications that do not respond to the PBT_APMQUERYSUSPEND event broadcast in the WM_POWERBROADCAST message.
    POWER_ACTION_LIGHTEST_FIRST = 0x10000000, // Uses the first lightest available sleep state.
    POWER_ACTION_LOCK_CONSOLE = 0x20000000,   // Requires entry of the system password upon resume from one of the system standby states.
    POWER_ACTION_DISABLE_WAKES = 0x40000000,  // Disables all wake events.
    POWER_ACTION_CRITICAL = 0x80000000,       // Forces a critical suspension.
}

[Flags]
public enum PowerActionEventCode : uint
{
    POWER_LEVEL_USER_NOTIFY_TEXT = 0x00000001,  // User notified using the UI.
    POWER_LEVEL_USER_NOTIFY_SOUND = 0x00000002, // User notified using sound.
    POWER_LEVEL_USER_NOTIFY_EXEC = 0x00000004,  // Specifies a program to be executed.
    POWER_USER_NOTIFY_BUTTON = 0x00000008,      // Indicates that the power action is in response to a user power button press.
    POWER_USER_NOTIFY_SHUTDOWN = 0x00000010,    // Indicates a power action of shutdown/off.
    POWER_FORCE_TRIGGER_RESET = 0x80000000,     // Clears a user power button press.
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
public struct POWER_ACTION_POLICY
{
    public POWER_ACTION Action;
    public PowerActionFlags Flags;
    public PowerActionEventCode EventCode;
}

public enum SYSTEM_POWER_STATE : UInt32
{
    PowerSystemUnspecified = 0,
    PowerSystemWorking = 1,
    PowerSystemSleeping1 = 2,
    PowerSystemSleeping2 = 3,
    PowerSystemSleeping3 = 4,
    PowerSystemHibernate = 5,
    PowerSystemShutdown = 6,
    PowerSystemMaximum = 7
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
public struct SYSTEM_POWER_LEVEL // SIZE MUST BE 24 bytes
{
    public byte Enable;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
    public byte[] Spare;
    public uint BatteryLevel;
    public POWER_ACTION_POLICY PowerPolicy;
    public SYSTEM_POWER_STATE MinSystemState;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
public struct SYSTEM_POWER_POLICY // SIZE MUST BE 232 bytes
{
    public uint Revision;
    public POWER_ACTION_POLICY PowerButton;
    public POWER_ACTION_POLICY SleepButton;
    public POWER_ACTION_POLICY LidClose;
    public SYSTEM_POWER_STATE LidOpenWake;
    public uint Reserved;
    public POWER_ACTION_POLICY Idle;
    public uint IdleTimeout;
    public byte IdleSensitivity;
    public byte DynamicThrottle;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
    public byte[] Spare2;
    public SYSTEM_POWER_STATE MinSleep;
    public SYSTEM_POWER_STATE MaxSleep;
    public SYSTEM_POWER_STATE ReducedLatencySleep;
    public uint WinLogonFlags;
    public uint Spare3;
    public uint DozeS4Timeout;
    public uint BroadcastCapacityResolution;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    public SYSTEM_POWER_LEVEL[] DischargePolicy;
    public uint VideoTimeout;
    public byte VideoDimDisplay;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
    public uint[] VideoReserved;
    public uint SpindownTimeout;
    public byte OptimizeForPower;
    public byte FanThrottleTolerance;
    public byte ForcedThrottle;
    public byte MinThrottle;
    public POWER_ACTION_POLICY OverThrottled;
}
```

Перечисление `POWER_INFORMATION_LEVEL` не стал добавлять, оставил лишь две нужные константы (`Ac`/`Dc`).

Comment: Ничего легче нету что ли?))))) я даже не знаю как и куда их впихнуть. Что вообще с ними делать? Извини я новичок просто

Comment: @Qwibern - _Что вообще с ними делать?_ - Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V, Ctrl+F5

Comment: Ух ты, и вправду заработало. Благодарю.